# Weights and bias giving Nan

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, nan

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
from pandas import DataFrame  
from random import shuffle  
import tensorflow as tf
```

Taking data from CSV file (IMDB dataset)

```
data=pd.read_csv('imdb.csv')  
data.fillna(-1)  
features=data.loc[:,['actor_1_facebook_likes','actor_2_facebook_likes','actor_3_facebook_likes','movie_facebook_likes']].as_matrix()  
labels=data.loc[:,['imdb_score']].as_matrix()  


learning_rate=.01  
training_epochs=2000  
display_steps=50  
n_samples=features.size
```

Defining placeholders for features and labels:

```
inputX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,4])  
inputY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
```

Defining weights and bias.
Weights and bias are coming out to be NaN.

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,4]))  
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4]))

y_values = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputX,w),b)
```

Applying neural network:

```
y=tf.nn.softmax(y_values)  
cost=tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(inputY-y,2))/2*n_samples  
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)  

with tf.Session() as sess:  
          sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  
          for i in range(training_epochs):  
              sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={inputX:features,inputY:labels})  
              if (i) % display_steps==0:  
                 cc=sess.run(cost,feed_dict={inputX:features,inputY:labels})  
                 print(sess.run(w,feed_dict={inputX:features,inputY:labels}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your learning rate is too big (try starting with `1e-3`).
Also, your neural network won't learn anything because you're starting from a condition in which your weights can't change: you have initialized your weights to zero, that's wrong.

Change your weights initialization to random values in that way:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,4]))
```

and you'll be able to train your network. (biases initialized to 0 are OK)

Comment: yes. I once initialized the weights with std=1, the weights will become NAN after a few epoch, When I change to std=1e-2, the training process works find. so initialization of weights is very import.

Answer (score 1):

Use `add_check_numerics_ops` of TensorFlow library to check which operation is giving you the nan values.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_check_numerics_ops